# Error: v(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to `react` and `react-router`. I am migrating from `react-router v2.8.1 to v4.1.1`. I am getting this error in the following code. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
const reactRouterDom = require<any>('react-router-dom');
let {BrowserRouter, Route} = reactRouterDom;
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter onUpdate={scrollToTop}>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: could you give more info about the error, what is your App file ? full error..

Comment: Sure. App.jsx contains rest of the routes and some layout related elements. I have debugged the code. A file named `invariant.js` throws this error directly after `ReactDOM.render` is called.

Comment: Here is the full stacktrace:
`invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: v(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

at invariant (invariant.js:44)    
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent 

(ReactCompositeComponent.js:188)

    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)

    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:215)

    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:649)

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora

Comment: Please I suggest you to edit your question and add the details on there. Including the render of your App component. The error sounds like on some render you didn't return ReactElement or null.

Comment: That's not the case. It works perfect on `react-router v2.8.1`. This error is coming due to the upgrade.